# PHP cURL vs. file_get_contents when using proxy

Tags: php, curl, proxy, file-get-contents

Running in Windows.

The following code works fine. I don't have specify a username and password when setting up the proxy.

```
$aContext = array(
'http' => array(
    'proxy' => 'tcp://ip:port', 
    'request_fulluri' => true,
),
);
$cxContext = stream_context_create($aContext);

echo file_get_contents("someurl", False, $cxContext);
```

However when I try this code it won't work unless I specify the username and password for the proxy.

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTP | CURLPROTO_HTTPS);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'http://ip:port');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "someurl");
    $responseBody = curl_exec($ch);
```

I get an HTTP 407 error (Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT) unless i specify the `http://domain\user:password@ip:port`

Any ideas how to make cURL work without specifying the user and password (like file_get_contents does)?

Comment: WHen using CURLOPT_PROXY try splitting the IP and Port section.
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'X.X.X.X');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 'XXXX');`

Comment: @Bijan same error when specifying url and port separately. just tried it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `CURLOPT_PROXY` and `CURLOPT_PROXYPORT` options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "123.123.123.123");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 8080);
```

It's unclear from your question, but if you need to use a username and password to authenticate with this proxy, then you can use the `CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD` option to specify your username and password and the `CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH` option to specify your authentication method:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "username:password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); //HTTP Basic auth
```

Also, depending on what type of proxy you are working with, you may need to specify the type in the `CURLOPT_PROXY` setting or separately via `CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE`.

**Documentation:**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html

Comment: Just tried this with IP and port specified separately and receive the same error.   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'x.x.x.x');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, '8080');

Comment: not 100% sure. The IT department has set it up (will try to find out). I know it is tracking the user who uses the proxy (and what I am doing is okay to do - just prefer to not have to hardcode a password in cURL). Almost feels like file_get_contents is pulling user credentials from Windows and passing them along.

Comment: "I know it is tracking the user who uses the proxy (and what I am doing is okay to do - just prefer to not have to hardcode a password in cURL). " -- I'm confused -- do you need to use a username/password to access the proxy or does it not require a username and password?

Comment: Using file_get_contents I do not have to specify a username/password. Using cURL it seems I do (so far). I am somewhat confused as well. Will try to find out more from the network folks and respond.

Comment: maybe the proxy's checking UA's and is allowing whatever ua that f_g_c uses, and requires a password for curl's.